After defining a var with "" in bash, when using the var do we need to use ""?
If we definde a var with "" like
Var="$1"

For protection the var from shell globbing and space, must we need to use var with "" or not? Or because we defined Var with "" from the very beginning, it is immune from shell globbing and spaces even if we don't use "" when using it? like
${Var}

Or
"${Var}"


It is in case that $1 contain special characters or spaces, for example if we have Var="hello world" and then we do a echo $Var it would print them splited echo then var and also for characters like * for example Var="*" and we do the echo var it might list all the directories instead of just *
